# Python: Making dummy variables on a long dataset with multiple records per index

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

I have a long dataset with a Patient identifier as the index ('PatientGuid') and a group. I would like to make one record per Patient with dummy indicators for group.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"PatientGuid" : ["00023761-9D8D-445B-874C-2424CC7CF620","00023761-9D8D-445B-874C-2424CC7CF620",
"00023761-9D8D-445B-874C-2424CC7CF620","0005D9BD-0247-4F02-B7EE-7C1B44825FA1",
"0005D9BD-0247-4F02-B7EE-7C1B44825FA1","0005D9BD-0247-4F02-B7EE-7C1B44825FA1",
"0005D9BD-0247-4F02-B7EE-7C1B44825FA1","0005D9BD-0247-4F02-B7EE-7C1B44825FA1",
"000B4862-7CE7-4EC5-8043-A97FCD74BD78","000B4862-7CE7-4EC5-8043-A97FCD74BD78"], 
"group" : ["600","272","909","789","272", "696", "v70", "692", "380", "401" ]})

df = df.set_index("PatientGuid")

df.info()
```

However, when I do pd.get_dummies, I end up with  multiple records for each patient.

```
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['group'], prefix="dx")
df2
```

Do I have to transform from long to wide before getting dummies? Can I process df2 and collapse all the 0s and 1s into one line?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, You can take a max based on `level=0`

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['group'], prefix="dx").max(level=0)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for such a quick and direct solution.